# Visual studio project builds but not run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, crash, project

Visual studio 2010 project build successfully but when we run, it does not launch executable.
This problem does not occur when I create vc++ win32 console application.
but when I create c# window form project or MFC dialog based application, project build successfully but does not run.
MFC dialog based application crash on run.

I am unable to debug program.

there is no problem in win32 console app.

all my projects were working fine with visual studio 2010 before this problem.

Please reply with some solution...

Thanks
Brajesh

Comment: Any hint on what the error is? What is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: 1. MFC dialog based application crash on run. Build successfully. exception occurs at dlgcore.cpp line no 366. c# form does not appear when I run the project